# Where condition on dependent entities causing slow performance Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
context.PaymentEntity.Include("UserPaymentEntity")
                     .Include("UserPaymentEntity.RefundEntity")
                     .Include("RequestEntity")
                     .Include("RequestEntity.PremiumEntity")
                     .Include("RequestEntity.PremiumEntity.TypeEntity")
                     .Include("RequestEntity.PremiumEntity.TypeEntity.CategoryEntity")
                     .Include("RequestEntity.PremiumEntity.TypeEntity.CategoryEntity.CategoryTypeEntity")
                     .Where(x => x.RequestKey != null && 
                                 x.RequestEntity.UserKey == usrKey && 
                                 '03/01/2016' <= x.ReceivedDate && 
                                 x.ReceivedDate <= '03/31/2016');
```

This where condition slows down the performance. Because it is accessing userKey from dependent entity.

How can I improve it? These tables have half a million to 1 million records in each table.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to have a look at the generated SQL.

Comment: Fyi, you are excluding nearly the whole `03/01` because the time portion is truncated. So `<= '03/31/2016'` means: give me everything before this day and also midnight.

Comment: Do you need all Included entities?

Comment: Yes, i need all of them, because i have to do some data manipulation from that list to display on the view.

Comment: you can use `.AsNoTracking()` to improuve performance, if you not plan to update the result of this query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make small queries and join them on memory, if possible.

2) Your query will not work you need a DbFunction for date and time '03/31/2016'

3) in your UserPaymentEntity you need `CategoryTypeEntity` entity, why you do not just add a navigation property in `UserPaymentEntity.CategoryTypeEntity`? this will reduce the joins hell.

4) when EF is struggling and can not achive your performance requirements, then just use Views.

5) use `nameof(UserPaymentEntity)` and not string `"UserPaymentEntity"` this is cleaner for refactoring.

6) This include:                     `.Include("RequestEntity.PremiumEntity.TypeEntity.CategoryEntity.CategoryTypeEntity")`

Will automatically include the whole navigation path `"RequestEntity"` and `"RequestEntity.PremiumEntity",` etc.
You to not have to write them all!

7) If you want only to read the data, then use:

```
this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

or get the data with `AsNoTracking`

8) Maybe you can divide your query logic in pages and use Take and Skip.

9) Use second level cash for the fixed data.https://efcache.codeplex.com/

Comment: I tried 6 and 7 for now. Seems improved performance a bit. i will try other suggestions and see. Thaks

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have went back to using SPROC's for large queries finding that the finite control over SQL is a much simpler approach. I'm not saying that the EF approach is bad but it just might be worth taking a SPROC into consideration so you can leverage temporary tables etc to further filter down your data set.